# Toshiba Laptop shuts down after 30 seconds

Tags: toshiba-laptop

When I start my laptop it boots up but after exactly 30 seconds it makes a "click" sound and shuts down.
Here are some tests I have performed:

1) changed my RAM memory 
          -> nothing changed

2) checked my hard drive for errors 
          -> nothing changed

3) started my laptop without hard drive 
          -> still shuts down after 30 seconds

4) took out my CD-ROM 
          -> nothing changed

5) my cooler is working fine, my laptop doesn't get overheated

6) the battery makes no difference if it's in the laptop or not

I've also made a log to see if it's always exactly 30 seconds. Here are the results:

### NORMAL BOOT

1)  31.17s

2)  31.45s

3)  30.78s

4)  30.34s

5)  31.23s

### F2 SETUP

1)  31.07s

2)  31.03s

### F2 SETUP AND EXIT

1)  30.52s

2)  31.13s

### F12

1)  31.28s

2)  30.97s

It doesn't mater how I start my laptop or what I do, after 30 seconds it just shuts down.
Can someone please help me? I can't find any solution on the web.

Comment: Just for clarification, do F2 & F12 take you to the BIOS?

Comment: How can you say your computer isn't overheating.  What you describe would fit perfectly with the CPU overheating.

Comment: Agree with Ramhound. Without extra info - laptop old/new? Did you disassembled/replaced parts lately? - that's what's the issue.

Answer (score 4):

A few possible causes are shown in forums:

1. Overheating: see http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-158211-toshiba-satellite-laptop-shuts-down-by-itself. If you can get to BIOS long enough to change CPU usage from *Dynamic* to *Always Low*, that might indicate (and partially resolve) issue. Have you cleaned the heat-sinks? Did you change clock timing that might cause overheating?
2. Improperly seated RAM (see above reference), unlikely since you've replaced it.
3. Bad CMOS battery: see http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/64361-35-laptop-turns-shuts-seconds-later-laptop
4. Bad battery: see http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/270289-toshiba-laptop-doesnt-start-up-2.html?s=c1b0db9809d35dced3d3a49c02109fb1. Though you've tested it working *just* from the mains, the power supply may need the additional filtering provided by a healthy battery.
5. Defective part, such as a voltage regulator or filter or bypass capacitor... if that's the case, hopefully it's still in warranty, since professional repair is needed.

Comment: 'im going to test him about overheating, I'v changed my RAM, I have to replace my CMOS battery? my lapotop is already like 2-3 years old i think, no warranty

Comment: If I change my CPU usage to always low and try zo save and exit my BIOS he saves and exits but then he gets back to the BIOS and I can't move anything and still after 30 seconds he shuts down